# Bezier curves in SVG

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I would like to draw Bezier Curves in SVG, and i know that the code looks like:

```
path.setAttributeNS(null, "d", "M5,5 C5,45 45,45 45,5")
```

but what to do if i want to give attributes on page i mean like:

```
circ.setAttributeNS(null, 'cx', x);
circ.setAttributeNS(null, 'cy', y);
circ.setAttributeNS(null, 'r', bokU);
```

where cx,cy,r are given from page text field after i submit it with button. I would like to draw them in loop so that every curve would be difrent.

Comment: What do you mean with "attributes on page"?  What's the "page text field"?  What submit button are you talking about?

Comment: well i mean that i give attribut to page like "x" or "r" in second code from tex field. I want to give each x and y position from text field

Comment: I'm still unclear about this.  What page?  Only elements can be given attributes, but neither HTML nor SVG have a `<page>` element AFAIKS.

Comment: I opened new topic with similar question but i think its beter explained so maybe you will be able to help with this one:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19362065/how-to-draw-bezier-curves-in-loop-with-svg