# How to draw Bezier Curves in loop with svg?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

So I know that to draw bezier curve you use:

```
path.setAttributeNS(null, "d", "M5,5 C5,45 45,45 45,5"):
```

But I would like to draw them in loop (not animation) and change their location every time, it will be same curve every time but with different start and end location. And I don't know how to change those attributes in loop.

From answer from bellow I tried in my code but it don't work. I know I did something wrong but I don't know what. Here is my code after modification:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
var x1 = 10;
var x2 = 15;
var x3 = 20;
var x4 = 30;
var x5 = 40;
var x6 = 50;
var x7 = 60;
var x8 = 70;

var attr = "M" + x1 + "," + x2 + " " + "C" + x3 + "," + x4 + " " + x5 "," + x6 + " " + x7 + "," + x8;

var path = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'path');
path.setAttributeNS("d", attr);
path.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "none");
path.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', '#'+Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16));
document.getElementById('svgOne').appendChild(path);

}
```

x`s are just to test if it works, so where i have made mistake???

Comment: There are at least three errors with your code. Use the browser developer tools and console to help you find them. There is one in the line where you set `attr`.  There is one in the line where you set "d". And finally the way you set a random stroke colour won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could recontruct the string:

```
var x1 = 5;
var x2 = 5;
var attr = "M" + x1 + "," + x2 + " C" + ...

path.setAttribute("d", attr);
```

Or alternatively use the [SVG DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#InterfaceSVGAnimatedPathData) so if you already have a single bezier curve

```
var move = path.pathSegList.getItem(0);
var curve = path.pathSegList.getItem(1);
```

then you can use the [SVGPathSegCurvetoCubicAbs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegCurvetoCubicAbs) interface to set the curve attributes e.g.

```
curve.x = 5;
curve.y = 10;
curve.x1 = 20
curve.y1 = 15;
curve.x2 = 12;
curve.y2= 13;
```

In your attempt

```
var attr = "M" + x1 + "," + x2 + " " + "C" + x3 + "," + x4 + " " + x5 "," + x6 + " " + x7 + "," + x8;

                                                                      ^ missing + sign
```

and

```
path.setAttributeNS("d", attr);
```

setAttributeNS takes 3 arguments or alternatively setAttribute takes 2.

```
path.setAttributeNS(null, 'stroke', '#'+Math.round(0xffffff * Math.random()).toString(16));
```

this does not always produce valid stroke syntax although occasionally it does so you will see some output some times.

browsers will report these issues in their error/web consoles so you really should try to take advantage of that.

Comment: Could you write whole code for your first solution?? I mean code that you know will draw curve. I am trying to implemt it but it dont work and i cant paste me code here for next 7 haurs

Comment: Yeah come on @Robert, why are you trying to make OP do the work? Write all the code for him, he's a busy man.

Comment: No thats not what i ment (thx for irony) i dont want you to write it for me but i try this solution and it not working. I know that i didnt do it right but i dont know where i made mistake. Thats why i ask for help.

Comment: @Jake edit your question with what you have tried and I'm sure people will be willing to help you :)